# Does Uploadifive works?

Tags: html, upload, uploadify, uploadifive

Any body ever buy the uploadifive from uploadify.com ? Does it work? Because the last update version was on 2012 . And I cant find the admin contact to ask if they already abandoned the plugin or they are still maintain it . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just bought it. Everything still seems to be from 2012, but it works fine for me!